# Writing file when closing window

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm writing a Restaurant Program.
When the user confirms his order, the order gets stored in an array of type order. **Why?** because when the user chooses to close the program, all orders get saved in a file with item's names and information about each item. 
Also, every order object has an array of type item inside it!

Could you help me on how to write that file? 
I know it'll be in the method processWindowEvent.

This is my try, i know that i should remove **textArea.getText()** but i don't know how to print all items, neither.

```
  protected void processWindowEvent(WindowEvent e){

         if (e.getID() == WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"All operation have been saved ");

            try{
               outFile=new File("Orderslist.txt");
               out=new FileOutputStream(outFile);
               ob=new PrintWriter(out);}
               catch(IOException M){M.getMessage(); }
            for(int i=0;i<o2.length;i++){
               if(o2[i]!=null){
                  if(o2[i].getCount()<=4)
                     ob.println(o2[i].toString()+"\n--------------\n"+textArea.getText()+"--------------\n"+"\nTotal: "+o2[i].getTotalPrice());

                  else if(o2[i].getCount()>4)
                     ob.println(o2[i].toString()+"\n--------------\n"+textArea.getText()+"--------------\n"+"\nTotal Price#: "+o2[i].getTotalPrice()+"\n\nDiscount 20%\n\n--------------\nTotal price#: "+(o2[i].getTotalPrice()-(o2[i].getTotalPrice()*0.2)));

               }
            }
```

Comment: There is no problem in closing method, the problem is that the text file that gets written is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor of your Widnow add this:

```
public Window() {
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
            writeFile(textArea.getText()); //Call your method
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

For writing the file:

```
File file = new File("myFile.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

bw.write("Texto to write");
bw.close();
```

Comment: What do you mean by constructure of my window?

Comment: Java basics: You have a class that represents your **Window/JFrame/Frame/etc** (**class MyWindow extends JFrame**). **Every class has a constructor**.

Answer (score 0):

After `ob.println()` do `ob.close();` or `ob.flush();`.

If you dont close the stream or flush the stream , nothing will be printed in your file.

Answer (score 0):

Really this isn't the best design, you should write changes to the file immediately as they are made. The reason for this is that if the application closes for any other reason (power cut, task manager kill, crash, etc) then you don't want to lose the user's data. It would also be worth automatically backing up that file (for example copying it after startup) so if you corrupt the current session somehow you can revert.

To actually implement the saving you want to use a FileOutputStream of some sort but the exact implementation will vary a lot depending on the format that you want the data inside the stream. For example XML, JSON, plan text, binary serialization etc are all fairly easy but you need to pick one :)